# Batch ECHO and echo

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have seen lots of people codes and some times the echo's are in capitals like:

```
echo hello
```

and

```
> "%Temp%\done.vbs" ECHO x=msgbox("message" ,6, "test")
```

Does it make any difference whether it is a echo or an ECHO.
Thanks if any one can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference, it's pure optic. `Cmd`/batch commands are always case insensitive. It doesn't matter to the parser if you write `ECHO`, `Echo`, `echo` or `eChO`.

Some people like it to write commands in Capitals because the code is a bit more readable.

Others (like me) use both versions, for example, `ECHO` for debugging messages (which will be removed later) and `echo` for permanent messages.

Comment: Additional info: people will use a character immediately after `echo` to avoid some issues, and `echo(` is the most reliable use to date.

Answer (score 0):

[image: No it will work either way.]

Nope, it does not matter if it is ECHO or echo, it will still work.